# Independent colums in an independent Sheet shift position when a macro is run

Tags: macros, libreoffice, calc

I have a 'seed' column, (Col C), in Sheet1. A button press executes a macro which generates data for 5 subsequent columns after Col C based on info in the seed data. I do a "paste special" (numbers only) of these 5 generated columns into Sheet2. Each column has 40 rows. Rows 15 to 20 are blank cells. After this, when I run any macro on the first sheet, the data in the first column inside Sheet2 moves up!! replacing the spaces in rows 15-20, offsetting my data! The other 4 columns in Sheet2 stay in the right location.
I've checked the macro that runs just before the data shifts up, and it has nothing to do with the Col C, or the macro operating on Col C's 'seed data'. The second macro is very similar to the first and pastes data much like the first but is independent (FYI the 'paste special' has 'Don't shift cells' option enabled). I suspect there's some kind of link to 'residual' kind of buffer somewhere that's causing this but I have no idea why/how this is happening??  {LibreOffice Version: 7.6.3.2}
Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: No, Micklos, just a verbal description is clearly not enough to find the source of the problem. We need both macro texts and data samples. The Q&A format of this resource does not allow for the sharing of sample files or for a detailed discussion. Try asking this question on some specialized forum.

Comment: Tq for the reply. I thought someone might recognise the problem and be able to propose a solution. It is truly strange. I could post the .ods. Any recommendations as to a good and relevant place to ask/post it?

Comment: The official page of LibreOffice TDF in the Help section suggests contacting the community at https://ask.libreoffice.org/ (it has two dozen sections for different languages, but judging by the number of messages, the English page is the most popular - which means you can get answers to your questions there fastest). The forum https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum is also very popular - it has existed for a very long time, formed long before the emergence of LibreOffice. Veterans of the forum are real experts in using office packages. Just try a simple search for these resources

Comment: I've been there a few times and seen your assistance to many others. OK I'll try, but right now I'm started trying some alternative ways which I feel may side-step the problem I was having.